# how to retrieve data from database using jquery and the same data should load into the bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, mdbootstrap

table

{

```
      <div class="container">
            <table id ="table" data-toggle="table" class="tabletable-striped table-hover display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th
                            data-field="EMPLOYEECODE"><b>EMPLOYEECODE</b></th>
                        <th
                            data-field="INDENTDATE"><b>INDENTDATE</b></th>
                        <th
                            data-field="INDENTNO"><b>INDENTNO</b></th>

                        <th
                            data-field="INDENTSHORTDES"><b>INDENTSHORTDES</b></th>
                        <th
                            data-field="REGISTEREDDATE"><b>REGISTEREDDATE</b></th>
                        <th
                            data-field="LINEITEMCODE"><b>LINEITEMCODE</b></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>

  }
```

html code
{

```
                     <form class="form-inline">
                        <div id="myapp" ng-app="myApp"
                             ng-controller="formCtrl">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2"
                                   id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search"> 
                                <button
                                   type="VIEW INDENTS" id="indents" class="btn btn-pink"><b>VIEW 
INDENTS</b></button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

}

JQuery code

{

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'coinsIndentsServlet',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 2500,
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "EMPLOYEECODE"},
                    {"data": "   INDENTDATE"},
                    {"data": "   INDENTNO"},
                    {"data": "   INDENTSHORTDES"},
                    {"data": "   REGISTEREDDATE"},
                    {"data": "   LINEITEMCODE"}

                ],
                success: function (result)
                {

                    console.log('complete with success and data:', result.indents);
                    $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', result.indents);

                }
            });
        });
```

}

coinsIndentsServlet.java

{

```
     protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    String empid = request.getParameter("empid");

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        coinsIndents egpsobj = new coinsIndents();
        JSONObject _output = egpsobj.getIndentDataForGrid(empid);

        out.write(_output.toString());
    }
}
```

}

i want to get the data  from the database and load into the bootstrap table ,
but the problem is when iam giving a employeeID into the search field with respect to that employeeID all data should be loaded into the bootstrap table.
how to do that? and here iam giving an url as an servlet not as  php , please suggest the answer using servlet not as php.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to narrow down where you are specifically having problems accomplishing the objective

Comment: iam having probelm with how to write a code using search field ID in jquery

Comment: Is this an angular app? The html suggests it is but question has no angular tag on it. If it is an angular app you wouldn't use jQuery at all for it

Comment: how to use the id of the search field into the JQuery based on that data should be displayed into the table

Comment: actually i tired using angular but sorry for that it is not based on angular

Comment: Suggest you find a tutorial for using jQuery with forms and ajax for starters. Shouldn't have any trouble finding lots of them

Comment: <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

    <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
      <div class="md-form my-0">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      </div>
      <button href="#!" class="btn btn-outline-white btn-md my-0 ml-sm-2" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

  </div>

Comment: this is my code

Comment: How does `empid` get pass in servlet ? Using form or ajax? Because I didn't find code related to that. Also add servlet tag as well in your question.

Comment: iam not passing an empid how to pass an employeeid using ajax, please help me out

Comment: @jyothikachapur Use onclick event and then get value from input-box and pass same to ajax ? what doesn't work here ?

Comment: can you tell how to do?